# What is $\cot(\pi/2)$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Base on the unit circle, I know

$
\begin{align}
&\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \\
=&\frac{0}{1}\\
=&0
\end{align}
$

But [it is also](https://mathway.com/default.aspx?p=ccal?p=cot%28SMB19SMB102%29?p=2?p=?p=?p=?p=?p=0?p=?p=0?p=?p=?p=Simplify)

$
\begin{align}
&\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \\
=&\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\\
=&\frac{1}{\frac{1}{0}}\\
=&undefined
\end{align}
$

And [Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=tan%28pi/2%29%5E-1&oq=tan%28pi/2%29%5E-1&gs_l=serp.3..0i8i30l10.6913.19159.0.19465.31.26.4.0.0.2.647.3197.10j14j1j5-1.26.0...0.0...1c.1.vPiuFfyk_vA) gives me this answer:

$6.12303177 × 10^{-17}$

I am really confused now. Although [I know](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cot%28pi/2%29) it is $0$, I don't see why [the other ones](http://mathway.com/answer.aspx?p=ccal?p=cot%28SMB19SMB102%29?p=2?p=?p=?p=?p=?p=0?p=?p=0?p=?p=?p=Simplify) are wrong.

Comment: What do you mean? The other ones are wrong because they disagree with the one that's right.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - I mean which step is wrong.

Comment: Well, Google doesn't give any steps, so I don't know what you mean by "which step is wrong". For the other one, you could say that $1/0$ isn't undefined, it's infinite, and $1/{\infty}=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - Why $1/∞$ is $0$?

Comment: @Derek Stare at [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Unitcirclecodefs.svg) long enough.

Comment: Derek, why shouldn't $1/\infty$ be zero?

Comment: Is it because of $lim_{(x\to∞)} \frac{1}{x} = 0$?

Comment: Yes, that tells you the only sensible interpretation of $1/\infty$ is zero. But if you want to be sure I see a question you ask me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$$\cot x = \frac{1}{\tan x}$$ only when $\tan x \neq 0$ (i.e. $x \neq n\pi$ for any $n\in \mathbb {Z}$).

However, $\cot x$ is actually *defined* as

$$\cot x := \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$ so $\cot \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$ is the correct answer.

Comment: To add to Argon's answer, the Google answer is due to numerical round-off error.

Comment: " cotx is actually defined as "  defined by who?  I have seen the definition as 1/tan x

Comment: @john Inter alia, the primitive definition in NIST's [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.14) is like this. The $1/\tan x$ definition contains periodic point (removable) discontinuities (as we see) that serve no purpose. You could define $\cot x$ as $1/\tan x$ and fill in all the gaps by taking the limit, but that is overkill.

Answer (score -2):

$\tan \frac π2$ is actually infinity.

So if we divide 1 by $\tan \frac π2$ we will have $\frac 1{\infty}$ which leads to 0.

$$\cot \frac π2 = \frac 1{\tan \frac π2}=0$$

Furthermore:

$$\cot x=\frac 1{\tan x}=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$

So:

$$\cot \frac π2=\frac{\cos \frac π2}{\sin \frac π2} = \frac 01 = 0$$

Comment: We can't 'divide' a number by $\tan (\pi/2)$; $\tan(x)$ is undefined at $x=\pi/2$, unless we edit the definition of tangent function.